# Is there a Free version for SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2019

I wonder if there is a SharePoint 2019 Foundation, I know that it's not the case for SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a free version, but a trial version in Azure.

See: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.SharePointServer2019Trial?tab=Overview

Answer (score 3):

No free or foundation version of the SharePoint server 2019. Only aviable option is use the trail version of SharePoint 2019 standard or enterprise.

You need a server OS in order to install it or you can use the Azure template as other mentioned.

You can download the bits of [SharePoint Server 2019 from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57462).